# Get user name/picture in FB app

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I only want a user's name and picture (such as you would see ready in a fb comment box on an external app). This info is fully available if I KNOW the user id (in this example, on line 58, they use what I assume is one of the FB devs, "Naitik": https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).

If the username and picture are publicly available (as the code comment suggests), can I get this for the user landing on my tab app? It seems silly that I can get that info with the user's id but not otherwise. I don't care about bdays, emails, employment, likes, nothing. I just want the "publicly available" info (i.e. without getting an OAuth token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that documentation means is that if you have identified your user, you can know his/her name, gender, and picture. You *still* have to authenticate them to identify them, however (as in, get their UID), and after that, the picture and name are available to you.

Comment: So I have to authenticate them solely to get info that is fully available to anyone that knows the userid? That just seems stupid and pointless. Basically I have to trade conversions for publicly available info. Wonderful job FB.

Comment: Think of it more as you have to authenticate them to know who they are. Otherwise, they're anonymous to you. It's sort of a pain, but I definitely see why they did that.

Comment: I guess I just don't see the point. I can search for any name on fb and then pull that info into my app. Anyone I don't know or have any connection with. It seems like a pointless double standard to me, especially as everywhere I go on the web, there is MY name and fb pic in every comment box. I guess I'd understand if I COULDN'T just take say http://graph.facebook.com/jimmysawczuk/picture and grab your fb pic ;)

Comment: There are lots of things you as a person can do through the UI that an app can't do, presumably to stop bots from simply sucking down the entire contents of Facebook's "publicly available info".

Comment: Well, if that's a problem, don't make any info public. There are bots that are scraping the data anyway. If data is "publicly accessible" and a user is IN FACEBOOK on my app I should be able to get this (I cannot stress enough how idiotic it is to not be able to get this info on THEIR platform). Very stupid and I'm not the only one who thinks so. Do a quick Google search! I can understand this on an external app, of course.

Comment: http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2011/02/facebook-dating/ -- doing a bang up job over there. http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/07/28/100-million-facebook-ids-compiled-online/ -- bang up job. Good thing they've only made it difficult for honest developers.